# Gradle is stuck on mergeDebugAssets, doesn't even fail

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project, which I run in Android Studio. I have ran this project before, but now I've made some changes (though I don't quite remember what I did), and then when I build it using Gradle, it gets stuck in `mergeDebugAssets`. I don't even get to see an error, it's just there, waiting for something to happen, apparently. I've tried cleaning too, but that gets stuck too, in the same step. I've tried running it from Android Studio and from the command line (with the `-d` option), but the result is the same, and there's no additional message that could help me start finding the problem.

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'maven'

version '1.1'
group 'com.baker'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21

        testApplicationId "com.baker.abaker.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            // Due to a bug in gradle 0.4.2 to 0.4.4 we use this way to get the maven local repository path.
            repository url: 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath
        }
    }
}
task install(dependsOn: uploadArchives)

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile project(':GooglePlayLicence')
    compile project(':GooglePlayDownloader')
}
```

The relevant output of `gradlew.bat assembleDebug -d`:

```
10:38:34.486 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :ABaker:mergeDebugAssets
10:38:34.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter                                                                    ]
Starting to execute task ':ABaker:mergeDebugAssets'
10:38:34.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter                                                                         ]
Determining if task ':ABaker:mergeDebugAssets' is up-to-date
10:41:46.358 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter                                                                          ]
Executing task ':ABaker:mergeDebugAssets' (up-to-date check took 3 mins 11.847 secs) due to:
  Output file H:\Proyectos\LGBT.Android\ABaker\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeAssets\debug has changed.
  Output file H:\Proyectos\LGBT.Android\ABaker\build\intermediates\assets\debughas changed.
  Output file H:\Proyectos\LGBT.Android\ABaker\build\intermediates\assets\debug\books\LGTB\assets\images\7_5_3_1@2x.jpg has changed.
10:41:46.371 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter                                                                       ]
Executing actions for task ':ABaker:mergeDebugAssets'.
10:41:46.391 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.RebuildIncrementalTaskInputs                                                              ]
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':ABaker:mergeDebugAssets'.
10:41:46.410 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Unable do incremental execution: full task run
10:41:56.735 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] deleteDir(H:\Proyectos\LGBT.Android\ABaker\build\intermediates\assets\debug) returned: true
```

It seems to detect a change in an image (7_5_3_1@2x.jpg), a change I am certain hasn't happened. My changes were made only in the Java code.

Comment: @WarrenFaith, how rude.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez but true, you got to understand what you ask: "I have a project which I do not expose that worked, I made some changes that I don't remember and now the compilation hangs"...

Comment: At least post your gradle file!

Comment: @shkschneider, OK, what additional details do you need?

Comment: Keep track of your changes. The task it hangs is `mergeDebugAssets` which is related to `assets` you put in your application. What are those? What did you had there?

Comment: @shkschneider, some images for a digital magazine. However, the changes I made were in code (the images aren't supposed to change anyway)

Comment: @shkschneider, I added more info

Comment: @dave, I added more info

Comment: Not sure who is responsible for my deleted comment but at least the OP started to provide more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem is not that the process is stuck, but that my project is so large, that one single change took more than an hour for the build to finish successfully.

Now I have to investigate why my project is so big, but that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Did you work out what caused the big jump in build time? I'm having the same problem with `mergeDebugAssets` hanging my build. I suspect a status file somewhere is locking it up ... but I've cleared every cache I can find...

Comment: @mm2001, it was a project with huge image files (think 1 GB total), and all that being served from an external hard drive.

Comment: Wow. Not the same as mine then. Thanks for the response. I just got mine running again by cloning a fresh copy of my repo. One copy builds, the other hangs on merge. Go figure. Technology 

Comment: I have the same problem and haven't been able to resolve it so far. It works if I don't rebuild after a new cloning of the Git sources.

Comment: same problem. Clean clone of repo works until I do a rebuild. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 9):

I just encountered this problem myself.

`:app:mergeDebugAssets` is related to whatever you've got in your `assets` folder.

I have a `myApp.realm` file there which wasn't a problem. The problem was that I had opened the file in Realm Studio, which had created a `myApp.realm.management` directory and `myApp.realm.lock` file in `assets`.

Deleting those generated files fixed my specific issue.

I hope this helps someone else landing here from Google.

Comment: In my case I had deleted `lock` and `management`, but there was still a 'pipe' file called `manifest.realm.note` that only showed from the command line. Deleting that fixed the build. This answer was the clue!